# ASP.NET Default.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Customer/Reservation/Default.aspx

How should i fix this? If I add Default.aspx to Folder Reservation that will fix my problem but is there any way to fix this error? :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The list of possible other ways is huge. What specific requirements do you have for not wanting a default.aspx?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `Default.aspx` is located in the virtual directory `Customer` or root and you're developing maybe a user control that has been added to a page in `/Customer/Reservation`?  If so, on the server-side, use `ResolveUrl`

```
Response.Redirect(ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx"));
```

or to create a link from that directory in markup, use:

```
<a href="<% = ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx") %>">Click here to go home</a>
```

However, if you're simply trying to navigate to `/Customer/Reservation` with the default page set to `Default.aspx` in IIS, then you'll have to add a `Default.aspx` page to the virtual subdirectory.

Comment: it is on may navigation bar.
how should i put that here 
<li><a href="Default.aspx" class="parent"><span>Home</span></a></li>

Comment: From server-side, you need to output results of `ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx")`, from the client markup, simply add `<% =ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx")%>`

Answer (score 0):

Just add the file. The reason it is giving you that error is because it cannot find the default document for the folder and (if I recall correctly) IIS does not by default display a listing of files within the folder.

I don't really see how you're experiencing a problem here. The error is fairly descriptive.

Comment: is there any other way?
http://localhost:6707/Default.aspx - i want when i click home it goes back to that link.
but when i add it to the Reservation Folder it looks like this
http://localhost:6707/Customer/Reservation/Default.aspx

Comment: To fix that specific error? No. HTTP 404 means that the web server cannot find or access the file you're trying to get it to access.

Comment: @LiamMcSherry, you're wrong. The solution for resolving non-existing `known` paths is simple - use routing/rewriting. You can then use urls like www.something.com/mypage.hahaha and still get the result you want.

Comment: so I have Home - default.aspx Reservation - reservation.aspx

i should add those webforms to every folder?

Answer (score 0):

You have basically two options:

Either `create that file` or `use routing to map that address to a desired file`.

Example of the second approach:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

private void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
   routes.MapPageRoute("customer-reservation", // name of the route
                       "Customer/Reservation", // url to look for
                       "~/Pages/reservation.aspx");  // existing file to map to
}
```

Note you need at least .NET version 4 or higher if you're using webforms, or use MVC for this to work. If you're using lower .NET version and not using MVC, you'd need an url rewrite module (search for it on Google, returns plenty of results).

Note2: this example belongs inside `Global.asax.cs` file.

Note3: another examples can be found here for instance: http://weblogs.asp.net/jalpeshpvadgama/archive/2011/12/11/easy-url-rewriting-in-asp-net-4-0-web-forms.aspx

If you need to find more resources on this topic, just type "asp.net routing" which shall give you enough results to learn from.

Comment: @CarloAdap, aaah, knew I forgot something. You need to put this inside your Global.asax file. Updating the answer to mention this fact.

Comment: RouteTable does not exist in the current context ? :| what should i do about that ?

Comment: @CarloAdap, have you resolved needed dependencies? Specifically `using System.Web.Routing;`

Comment: @CarloAdap , <%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>